# The category of finitely generated abelian groups does not have enough injectives

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, injective-module

I am looking for a hint for the following exercise:

> Show that the category of finitely generated abelian groups does not
>   have enough injectives.

What would be a good way to start proving this?

Comment: Well, injectives have to be divisible.

Comment: @Randall Yes, this is something I considered but I imagine I’d have to find an object X such that there won’t be an injective I and a mono from X to I. My difficulty is that I don’t know where to look for such an X...

Comment: How can $\mathbb{Z}$ map to a divisible group to satisfy the universal property of an injective?  And, the divisible group must be finitely generated!

Comment: Literally any nontrivial $X$ works.  Beware though that you can't just use the fact that injective abelian groups are divisible directly, since injectiive objects in the subcategory of finitely generated abelian groups are not necessarily the same as injective objects in the category of all abelian groups.

Comment: Good point.${}{}{}$

Comment: @EricWofsey But being divisible is the same thing as injectivity for the morphisms $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$, so Randall's comment is still correct.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: There are actually *no* nontrivial injective objects at all.  To prove this, you can use the classification of finitely generated abelian groups.  Given any nontrivial finitely generated abelian group, you just need to find a way to include it into a larger group such that it is not a direct summand.  (In fact, since a direct summand of an injective object is injective, you just have to check this for cyclic groups!)

Comment: Thank you, Eric, for this answer. I think I now see where this is going, although I don't really see how such an inclusion could work. Even for the case of $G = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ if this inclusion $G\rightarrow H$ has to be a group homomorphism then I struggle to see how it is possible to make sure that $G$ won't be a direct summand of $H$.